# Set executable permissions in file from Android application

Tags: android, executable, file-permissions, chmod

I want to make one `Android` application, that first will download the android `tcpdump` binary and second will execute it. The file was downloaded successfully, but I can't set executable:

```
try 
{
    File file = new File( "/sdcard/tcpdump" );

    if ( file.exists() )
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[]{ "su", "-c", "chmod 777 /sdcard/tcpdump" } );
    }
} 
catch ( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Files located on `SD` card aren't executable by default. Move the file to internal storage, namely to `data/local/tmp`. The files under the directory "get" world-executable permission.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to set these permissions (rwx rwx rwx) on the file using:

```
file.setReadable(true, false); //Sets everyone's permissions to readable
file.setWritable(true, false); //Sets everyone's permissions to writable
file.setExecutable(true, false); //Sets everyone's permissions to executable
```

The first parameter sets the permission to `true` and the second parameter sets the `ownerOnly` parameter to `false`, meaning the permission gets applied to all users.

You shouldn't need to execute a Runtime command to set permissions on a file.
You can just use the helper methods on the [File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) class.
Here are links to the individual method docs: [setReadable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setReadable(boolean,%20boolean)), [setWritable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setWritable(boolean,%20boolean)), and [setExecutable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setExecutable(boolean,%20boolean))